# SSL for example.com and www.example.com?

Tags: ssl

I'm new in installing certificates in IIS 7.5 (Windows Server 2008 R2). I have installed a SSL certificate for my site where the Common Name is example.com. But, if I try to reach the site using www.example.com I get the certificate name mismatch error (http://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/certificate-name-mismatch-error.htm) So, how to fix it ? I mean, one SSL certificate for multiple domains, is it possible ?

Comment: @haim770 Who signs the certificate (self signed or signed by a recognized CA will not change anything). A wildcard certificate will work but will allow too much (e.g., hackedsite.example.com) in addition to the allowed names.

Comment: I misunderstood the question, i thought it's some kind of a 'demo' website with a real 'example.com' domain (defined in the 'hosts' file or something).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can configure aliases in your certificate (called "Subject Alternative Name") in addition to the common name (CN). You **don't** need a wildcard certificate which would allow too much (any subsite): you can just list the alternate names you want.

If you are using OpenSSL take a look at the [config man page](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/x509v3_config.html#Subject_Alternative_Name_)

For example (OpenSSL config snippet):

```
...    

[ req ]
default_bits            = 2048
default_keyfile         = privkey.pem
distinguished_name = dn
prompt = no
encrypt_key = no
req_extensions = req_ext

[dn]
C=XX
O=Example
CN=example.org

[req_ext]
subjectAltName = DNS:example.org,DNS:www.example.org

....
```

Comment: I'll be very helpful how can I do this

Comment: It depends. Are you generating the certificate request yourself?

Comment: Yes, I have generated a CSR request and my client sent me back a text file by which I could finish the CSR request (and install the certificate)

Comment: the certificate is signed by RapidSSL CA, if it matters

Comment: is this OpenSSL required ? How can I obtain a privkey.pem file ?

Comment: you created a private key during the CSR phase.

Comment: @Tony not OpenSSL is not required it just the most common. If you need help in the CSR generation you have to specify how you are generating it. `privkey.pem` should be substituted with the name of the file containing the certificate private key.

Comment: @Matteo I've generated the CSR request in the same way as here http://www.digicert.com/csr-creation-microsoft-iis-7.htm

Comment: @Tony digicert also sells certificates with subject alt names. See http://www.digicert.com/subject-alternative-name.htm

Comment: but the certificate is signed by http://www.rapidssl.com/

Comment: @Tony I don't see any specific instruction on their homepage. A quick Google search shows a couple of announcements that they also sell them but for the details I would just contact their support.

Comment: they redirects me to Geotrust but they offer GeoTrust Wildcard SSL

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34892/discussion-between-tony-and-matteo)